# why is the table border not showing in this html table

Tags: html

I have a simple html table like this: http://jsbin.com/oxiyi

I want to have a border with color #990000 outside the entire table.  So I have made a table outside the table and given it border color of #990000.  But still I dont see a border color.

Answer (score 25):

Use the border property with CSS style and give it the color. I got rid of the nested tables in your example as well.

```
<style>
td {
    border: solid 2px lightgrey;
}
</style>
<table style="border: 5px solid #990000; border-collapse: collapse">
```

http://jsbin.com/odici

That preserves your borders on your cells...

Answer (score 19):

Tables inside tables! Oh noes! My head hurts.

You should be glad that doesn't work, as it is awful markup and should be avoided at all costs. Looking at your HTML code I am noticing a lot of inline properties being set and lack of CSS being used. You should really read up on CSS, as the code you have right now looks more like  the code that was being produced in 2000 rather than what we're doing nowadays. In short, however, you can get rid of your outer table and add a style declaration of `border: 1px solid #990000;` in the table to get the effect you want. This is just the tip of the iceberg, however, and you really should read up on CSS and valid markup before your website self implodes. :)

Comment: CSS oh noesss i'm gonna fall asleep...i know i know. i really should :(

Comment: I really want to have no inline css in my tags because it makes me not want to open my html files. however, i've inherited most of this sites code from someone. I am developing some new pages so just copied the content from another page. I'll try my best to have no inline css in this page.  But i'll need help. so look out for my questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the outer table has border set to 0

Change border =0 to border=1

Answer (score 2):

A better method would be to remove the outer table and add the border via CSS:

```
<table ... style='border: 1px solid #900'>
```

Better still, use an external stylesheet to style the table.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

1. A `<div>` would be a better tool for
   this job
2. Your outer table has `bgcolor`
   specified, not `bordercolor`
3. Your outer table has `border` set to
   0
4. You need to also include a `<tr>`
   and `<td>` around the inner table to
   make your HTML correct

Like this:

```
<table name='outerTable'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table name='innerTable'>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two styles to the code:

1. Added "border-collapse: collapse" style to table tag
2. Added "border: 1px solid gray" style to all td tags

```css
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

border-collapse: collapse
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code

```
tr .bordered{
      border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
```

the while calling it use

```
<tr class="bordered"></tr>
```

Comment: He wants a border outside of the `table`. using  `boredered` class on `<tr>` tag  will affect only the bottom `table` rows.

Comment: use table.border instead of tr them change the class tag to the table tag

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you exactly why your tables are not interacting correctly without seeing your markup, but I do see a problem with your fundamental approach.

Instead of another table, wrap your table in a DIV tag like this:

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #990000;"> 
   <your table> 
</div>
```

This better adheres to modern standards for HTML/XHTML.

Without seeing your code, I can't tell you whether your inner table adheres to best practices or not.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

- Create one custom css file in '/css ' dir, say 'local.css'

  - Add following code in marinelli.info file.
    stylesheets[all][] = css/local.css
  - Try adding following css code in your custom css (i.e. local.css) file :

  tbody {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  }

  tr, tr.even {
    background: #dedede;
  }

  table tr th {
    background: #757575;
  }

  tr td, tr th {
    border: 1px solid white;
  }

  table tr th, table tr th a, table tr th a:hover {
    color: white;
  }

  - Please clear cached data here- /admin/config/development/performance

  Rgrds,